# Onde está o problema deste código?

Tags: php, php-7

Onde estou errando ao atualizar este código para php 7.4.

Arquivo "controles/conexao.php"

```
<?php 
// DADOS DA HOSPEDAGEM 
$endereco = "localhost"; 
$usuario = "root"; 
$senha = ""; 
$banco = "teste";

// CONEXÃO DASHBOARD
$link = mysqli_connect($endereco, $usuario, $senha);
mysql_select_db($banco, $link);
?>
```

Arquivo "dashboard.php"

```
<?php
include("controles/conexao.php");

//BUSCAR USUARIO
$buscarusuario = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE estado_usuario = 0  AND vendedor = 1", $link);

//PEGAR QUANTIDADE
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($buscarusuario);

//MOSTRAR QUANTIDADE
echo "$num_rows\n";
?>
```

Comment: A função mysql_select_db() foi removida a partir da versão 7.0.0

Comment: Qual função a subistituiu?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Comment: Como eu poderia deixar este código funcional?

Comment: Fia a resposta rápida aqui mesmo, tem que revisr

Comment: veja isso também https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgbXR.png

Comment: para ter uma visão rápida do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A função mysql_select_db() foi removida a partir da versão 7.0.0**

Arquivo "controles/conexao.php"

```
<?php 
// DADOS DA HOSPEDAGEM

$endereco = "localhost"; 
$usuario = "root"; 
$senha = ""; 
$banco = "teste";

$link = new mysqli($endereco, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

// Check connection
if ($link->connect_error) {
  printf("Conexão falhou: " . $link->connect_error);
  exit();
}

?>
```

Arquivo "dashboard.php"

```
<?php
include("controles/conexao.php");

//BUSCAR USUARIO
$buscarusuario = ("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE estado_usuario = 0  AND vendedor = 1");

//PEGAR QUANTIDADE
$result = mysqli_query($link, $buscarusuario);

//MOSTRAR QUANTIDADE
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Comment: A recompensa é poder te ajudado! :-)